# Verify Linux service running or not using java

Tags: linux, java, services

How to verify if a Linux service is running or not using java command ?
i.e how to check if my mysqld service is start or not using java ?

Comment: Where is your `pid` for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **java.io.File** you can check for the existance of a file. A `pid` file is a process ID file that returns the Process ID (as found in `ps aux`) of the process that is running. Chances are if the `pid` file of your mysql instance exists then the service is running. However, there have been cases where the `pid` file will still exist if the mysql instance crashed abruptly instead of exiting normally.

In this example, my `mysql pid` file is located under `/run/mysqld`

```
File f = new File("/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"); 
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory())

{ code here }
```

You can find yours by running something like this in a terminal window.

`sudo find / | grep pid | grep mysql`

Comment: hey hw do i find location of the pid of any service ?

Comment: This solved my above query -->http://servercomputing.blogspot.in/2012/08/find-process-id-in-fedora-centos-redhat-linux.html